# InvalidOperationException and Workflows in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to query a running state machine workflow using `StateMachineWrokflowInstance` in ASP.NET MVC.

Here is the scenario:

1. Workflow runtime configuration: added `SqlWorkflowPersistenceService`, `ManualWorkflowSchedulerService`, `ExternalDataExchangeService` and registered custom `ExternalDataExchange` service with `ExternalDataExchangeService`;
2. Execution sequence:

   ```
   var instance = WorkflowRuntimeHandle.CreateWorkflow(type);
   instance.Start();
   WorkflowRuntimeHandle.GetService<ManualWorkflowSchedulerService>
   ().RunWorkflow(instance.InstanceId);

   var stateMachineWorkflowInstance = new
   StateMachineWorkflowInstance(instance.WorkflowRuntime, instance.InstanceId);
   ```
3. Received error:

   ```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Workflow with id "[GUID]" not found in 
   state persistence store?
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this exception could have many causes.

I found a way to detect the culprit.
I added handlers for all the workflow runtime events and stored the sequence as history in a list and discovered from the list that after `RunWorkflow` is called the workflow was terminated.

The `WorkflowTerminated` event parameter `WorkflowTerminatedEventArgs` comes with a `Exception` property which includes inner exceptions that showed the real source of the problem.

I'm posting this here in hope that this experience would be beneficial to those who are reading.